# Selecting max revision with Linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

I've looked over some other answers and none seemed to be exactly what I'm looking for and I could not get further with those questions than I currently am.

I have a single table that houses all of our documents and revisions.

I currently have this Linq:

```
from v in IPACS_Versions
where v.DateApproved == null
group v by v.DocumentID into g
select g.Max(t => t.Revision)
```

This correctly gives me the items that need revisions, however I need to select all of the fields and currently it is only selecting the Revision field.  I am very new to Linq, how can I change this?

More Detail in case my above code is completely wrong.

I need to select the entire row for the max revision for each document.  The primary key is documentId, and each documentId can have many different revisions, I need the most recent one.  The other criteria is there is a field dateApproved that is null if it has not been approved yet, so the max revision or any item that has not been approved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is querying against a database, you probably want:

```
from v in IPACS_Versions
where v.DateApproved == null
group v by v.DocumentID into g
select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.Revision).First()
```

If it's running locally (LINQ to Objects), you can use the [`MaxBy`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) method of [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com):

```
from v in IPACS_Versions
where v.DateApproved == null
group v by v.DocumentID into g
select g.MaxBy(t => t.Revision)
```